# A Theorem on exterior deravitives

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, differential-topology, differential-forms, tensors

From Chapter 7 of Arnolds "Mathematical Methods in Classical Mechanics".

$Theorem:$ Given a manifold $M$, There is a unique (k+1)-form $\Omega$ on $TM_x$ which is the principal (k+1)-linear part at 0 of the integral over the boundary of a curvilinear parallelepiped, $F(v_1,...v_{k+1})$; i.e.

(1) $F(\epsilon v_1,.... \epsilon v_{k+1}) = \epsilon^{k+1} \Omega(v_1,.....,v_{k+1}) + o(\epsilon^{k+1})$ ($\epsilon \rightarrow 0$).

Where $F(v_1,...v_{k+1})=\int_{\delta \amalg} w^k$ where $\delta \amalg$ is the boundary of a k+1-parallelepiped

---

Can somebody help me understand this theorem?

What does it mean to be "the principal linear part"? And what is going on in (1)? What is the deal with Epsilons and what is $o(\epsilon^{k+1})$?

Comment: Arnold defines $F$ in terms of a $k$-form $\omega$, did that definition make sense? I think by principal $(k+1)$-linear part, he means the term in $F$ which is "of order $\epsilon^{k+1}$" in the $v_i$'s. That is, if we multiply our vectors by a scale $\epsilon$, the function $\Omega$ is something like $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} F(\epsilon v) / \epsilon^{k+1}$. Everything in the $o(\epsilon^{k+1})$ is higher than $(k+1)$th order in $\epsilon$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation.
(Not sure if that helps.)

Comment: What do you mean by the terms in $F$ which is "of order $\epsilon^{k+1}$? I mean, $F$ is an integral, do you mean the terms in the $k$ form that we are integrating? I'm still confused hah  but thanks for the article link.

Comment: So if you fix all the vectors $v_i$, consider the function $\epsilon \mapsto F(\epsilon v)$, and imagine the Taylor expansion in $\epsilon$. I understood the theorem as saying that the coefficients of $\epsilon^j, j\leq k$ vanish, and the $(k+1)$ coefficient happens to be a $(k+1)$ form (applied to the vectors $v_i$).